# Is it possible to set an auto reply email for “contact us” form

Tags: magento-1.9, contact-us, response

I'm wondering is it possible to create an auto reply message to emails received through contact-us form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no core facility for this. You could either write / locate a custom extension to do it, or you could probably do it via your e-mail provider by setting up an auto-responder for the e-mail address the contact form sends to.